# Responsive HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

I am using the following css code:

```
html {
    background: #2B2B2B url(images/bg.gif) repeat;
}
body {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header,
footer,
aside {
    display: block;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    text-decoration: underline;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0px dotted red;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
input,
select {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
select {
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
button {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #333333;
    color: #FFFCEC;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
button:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#edit {
    background: #DC5B21;
}
#delete {} #course,
#name,
#profesor,
#subject {
    background: #ABDCD6;
}
label {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #282827;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0.5rem;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ABDCD6;
}
th {
    background: #E9633B;
}
th,
td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
td {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ABDCD6
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #DCD8CF
}
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.headerbar {
    width: 988px;
    float: left;
}
.headerbar.top {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 102, 13, 1) 3%, rgba(255, 109, 22, 1) 32%, rgba(255, 121, 38, 1) 77%, rgba(255, 121, 38, 1) 100%);
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 19px 30px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: #938D94 7px 7px 5px;
}
.headerbar.bottom {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 102, 13, 1) 3%, rgba(255, 109, 22, 1) 32%, rgba(255, 121, 38, 1) 77%, rgba(255, 121, 38, 1) 100%);
    min-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 37px 34px;
    box-shadow: #938D94 7px 1px 5px;
}
.leftbar {
    width: 50%;
    background: #EB593C;
    min-height: 605px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px dashed #282827;
}
.rightbar {
    width: 47%;
    background: #221E1D;
    min-height: 595px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #EB593C;
    box-shadow: #938D94 5px 5px 5px;
}
#submit,
#clear {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #FF9933;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .leftbar,
    .rightbar {
        float: none;
    }
    .headerbar.top h1 {
        margin-left: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }
```

and here is my  HTML page very simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My web app</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="mystyle2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script>
            var studentsArray = [];
            var selectedIndex = -1;
            function init() {
                document.getElementById("tablerows").innerHTML = "";
                if (localStorage.studentsRecord) {
                    studentsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.studentsRecord);
                    for (var i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
                        prepareTableCell(i, studentsArray[i].course, studentsArray[i].name, studentsArray[i].profesor, studentsArray[i].subject);
                    }
                }
            }
            function onRegisterPressed() {
                if(validate()){
                var course = document.getElementById("course").value;
                var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var profesor = document.getElementById("profesor").value;
                var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
                var stuObj = {course: course, name: name, profesor: profesor, subject: subject};
                if (selectedIndex === -1) {
                    studentsArray.push(stuObj);
                } else {
                    studentsArray.splice(selectedIndex, 1, stuObj);
                }
                localStorage.studentsRecord = JSON.stringify(studentsArray);
                init();
                onClarPressed();
            }else{

            }
            }
            function prepareTableCell(index, course, name, profesor, subject) {
                var table = document.getElementById("tablerows");
                var row = table.insertRow();
                var courseCell = row.insertCell(0);
                var nameCell = row.insertCell(1);
                var profesorCell = row.insertCell(2);
                var subjectCell = row.insertCell(3);
                var actionCell = row.insertCell(4);
                courseCell.innerHTML = course;
                nameCell.innerHTML = name;
                profesorCell.innerHTML = profesor;
                subjectCell.innerHTML = subject;
               actionCell.innerHTML = '<button id="edit" onclick="onEditPressed(' + index + ')">Edit</button><br/><button id="delete" onclick="deleteTableRow(' + index + ')">Delete</button>';
            }
            function deleteTableRow(index) {

                studentsArray.splice(index, 1);
                localStorage.studentsRecord = JSON.stringify(studentsArray);
                init();
            }
            function onClarPressed() {
                selectedIndex = -1;
                document.getElementById("course").value = "";
                document.getElementById("name").value = "";
                document.getElementById("profesor").value = "";
                document.getElementById("subject").value = "Math";
                document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "Register";
            }

            function onEditPressed(index) {
                selectedIndex = index;
                var stuObj = studentsArray[index];
                document.getElementById("course").value = stuObj.course;
                document.getElementById("name").value = stuObj.name;
                document.getElementById("profesor").value = stuObj.profesor;
                document.getElementById("subject").value = stuObj.subject;
                document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "Update";

            }


             function validate(){

                var errors = [];


                var re = /^[\w]+$/;
                var id = document.getElementById("course");
                if(id.value==="" ){
                    errors.push("Course name is empty");
                }else if(id.value.length<3){
                    errors.push("Course name is to shoort");
                }else if(!re.test(id.value)){
                    errors.push("Input contains invalid characters");
                }

                var name = document.getElementById("name");
                var regEx = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/; 
                if(name.value===""){
                    errors.push("Name cannot be empty");
                }else if(!regEx.test(name.value)){
                   errors.push("Name contains invalid characters");
                }

                var profesor = document.getElementById("profesor");
                if(profesor.value===""){
                    errors.push("Professor field cannot be empty");
                }else if(!regEx.test(profesor.value)){
                    errors.push("Professor field contains invalid characters");
                }

                if(errors.length>0){
                    var message = "ERRORS:\n\n";
                    for(var i = 0;i<errors.length;i++){
                        message+=errors[i]+"\n";
                    }
                    alert(message);
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">





            <header class="headerbar top"><h1>ITEC3506: Assignment#2</h1></header>



            <aside class="leftbar">


                <div>

                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="course"><span>Course Name</span></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name of course" id="course">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" id="name">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="profesor">Course Professor</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter course Professor" id="profesor">
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <select id="subject">
                            <option value="Math">Math</option>
                            <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
                            <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
                            <option value="English">English</option>
                            <option value="CS">CS</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label for="submit"> </label>
                        <button id="submit" onclick="onRegisterPressed()">Submit</button>
                        <button id="clear" onclick="onClarPressed()">Clear</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

            </aside>

            <aside class="rightbar">
                <table id="regtable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Course</th>
                            <th>Student</th>
                            <th>Professor</th>
                            <th>Subject</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tablerows">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </aside>
            <footer class="headerbar bottom"></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I transform this code into a responsive site.
Everything is resizing normally, except I cannot seem to resize my table and form. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you attach a fiddle please?

Comment: It is my first time using fiddle but here you go https://jsfiddle.net/wpsgk91o/

Comment: I see an unecessary div closing after, footer. After you remove it, can you check?

Comment: I also see that you are setting `fieldset` to 400px width, but not setting a `max-width`. If a fully responsive look is the goal, you need to ensure that there is a `max-width: 100%;` on that so that it does not cause a scrollbar to appear below 400px.

Comment: nothing changes i think the problem is in css file because i cant seem to resize the form or the table ???

Comment: OK i added max-width:100% in fieldset and now register and delete button are moving but the form is still staying??

Comment: See my full answer below. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things going on here.

First, you don't have a set width on a few of your fields, so change:

```
fieldset{
    border: 0px dotted red;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to:

```
fieldset{
    border: 0px dotted red;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also change `.headerbar` from `width: 988px;` to `width: 100%;`.

For responsive frameworks, you need to ensure that you never have a set a fixed `width`  without ensuring there is a `max-width` attached to it, otherwise your content size will never drop below the size of your fixed width.

Second, I noticed the following:

```
.leftbar{
    width: 50%;
    background: #EB593C;
    min-height: 605px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 3px dashed #282827;
}
```

You didn't specifically call this out, but when I check your code in a smaller view, I notice that your `width: 50%;` is causing the backgrounds to look off, which does not seem to be your intention. I would recommend adding `.leftbar { width: 100%; }` as well as `.rightbar { width: 100%; }` inside of `@media screen and (max-width:700px){`

That just leaves the `table`. Tables do not automatically break down, so are generally not something we want to use when developing a responsive site, but of course sometimes there is no getting around this.

There are a few ways to tackle the issue with the `table`. One is to set the `table` to `display:block;` and apply `overflow-x: scroll;` to it inside of your `@media screen and (max-width:700px){`, which will allow the user to scroll left/right when viewing it from smaller screens. Another is to use one of the various Javascript plugins that can achieve this.

Hope this helps get you on the right track. Best of luck!

Comment: I try it now still can get table to work but everything else is working fine ,thank you

Comment: Great, if you could please accept the answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thak you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Not a problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

Do not set width for these

```
input,select{/*width: 400px;*/}
fieldset{/*width: 400px;*/}
```

If you are setting width obviously you cannot obtain a responsive layout